# How can I replace the date picker with a text field that shows a date picker when it has the focus?

Tags: 7, forms, datetime

I installed the *Date Picker* module, which works fine. This is what appears when I add the *datepicker* element to the form.

> [image: screenshot]

This is the code I use to add the *datepicker* element.

```php
$form['date'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Select your birthdate'),
  '#type' => 'datepicker',
  '#date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
  '#date_year_range' => '-100:+0',
  '#default_value' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()),
);
```

I want to display a text field; when it has the focus, the calendar should be shown.

How should I change the code to make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [**DatePicker inline**](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_datepicker_inline) module?

From module page:

> This module permits inline rendering of date's popup widget. That is,
>   it display the datepicker embedded in the page instead of in an
>   overlay.
>
> It integrates with **field API**, **form API** and **views exposed
>   filters** (via date_views).